# Average column by specific datetime associated values

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement, excel-formula, average

I have one column with the time in format "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" and another with the temperature for that time point. I am looking to calculate the average temperature of the day and night of each month separately. I.e. average all temperatures between 06:00 and 18:00 in May and all temperature between 18:00 and 06:00 in May and then the same for March and so on.

```
    Time    Celsius(C)
06/05/2016 10:49    28
06/05/2016 11:49    29
06/05/2016 12:49    31
06/05/2016 13:49    27.5
06/05/2016 14:49    24
06/05/2016 15:49    25
06/05/2016 16:49    24.5
06/05/2016 17:49    23.5
06/05/2016 18:49    23
06/05/2016 19:49    22.5
06/05/2016 20:49    22.5
```

I am currently using the following formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C3643,B2:B3643,">=01/05/2016",B2:B3643,"<=31/05/2016",B2:B3643,">=01/05/2016 06:00",B2:B3643,"<=31/05/2016 18:00")
```

To try and calculate an average if the date is within May and during the day - however it doesn't appear to be working and when I change the hour periods it still spits out the same number (which is the average for the month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a long SUMPRODUCT Formula:

For the 600 to 1800 in May:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12>=DATE(2016,5,1))*($A$2:$A$12<=DATE(2016,5,31))*(MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)>=TIME(6,0,0))*(MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)<=TIME(18,0,0))*B2:B12)/SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12>=DATE(2016,5,1))*($A$2:$A$12<=DATE(2016,5,31))*(MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)>=TIME(6,0,0))*(MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)<=TIME(18,0,0)))
```

You can always replace all the DATE() and TIME() parts with cell references instead of hard coding them.

[image]

To get the between 1800 and 600 we need to shift it to an `OR` with `+` between the Time Boolean instead of `*`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12>=DATE(2016,5,1))*($A$2:$A$12<=DATE(2016,5,31))*((MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)<=TIME(6,0,0))+(MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)>=TIME(18,0,0)))*B2:B12)/SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12>=DATE(2016,5,1))*($A$2:$A$12<=DATE(2016,5,31))*((MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)<=TIME(6,0,0))+(MOD($A$2:$A$12,1)>=TIME(18,0,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this - it appears to work when you do between 06:00-18:00 but not when you swap it around to between 18:00-06:00, do you know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

This relies on you creating a table of months and time ranges like below:

[image]

Enter this formula in E2 and drag around as needed. It's an array formula, so must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(
 ((MONTH($A$2:$A$101)=MONTH(E$1&1))*
 ((MOD(HOUR($A$2:$A$101)-LEFT($D2,2),24))>=0)*
 ((MOD(HOUR($A$2:$A$101)-LEFT($D2,2),24))<12)),
$B$2:$B$101))
```

Notes:

- The `MONTH(E$1&1)` part lets you get a month number from text like
  "Jan"
- I used MOD and subtraction of the left part of the time range to get
  the target hour in a range from 0 to 23. This made it possible to filter on values between 1 and 11.
- If [Barry Houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini) were still around he could do it in half the space, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

While working with datetime and when the actual day is reckoned beyond midnight like in 18 hrs to 6 hrs the next day, I find it useful to offset the time back and do the calculations.

6:00 to 18:00    =AVERAGE(IF((MONTH($A$2:$A$12-0.25)=D2)*(MOD($A$2:$A$12-0.25,1)<0.5),$B$2:$B$12,""))

18:00 to 6:00    =AVERAGE(IF((MONTH($A$2:$A$12-0.25)=D2)*(MOD($A$2:$A$12-0.25,1)>=0.5),$B$2:$B$12,""))

These are array formulas entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Here I am offsetting time by 0.25 days which is 6 hours.

[image]